# React Toggle Functionality

Tags: reactjs, components, state, toggle, react-props

[Current Project Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yageY.png)

I have a Content component that renders 2 Panel components. The Content component passes its state to panel 1 and passes !state to panel 2. (Panel 1 is initially visible and panel 2 is not)

Desired Functionality:

- When the user clicks the "hidden" component, it sets it to visible and hides the visible one.
- If the user clicks the now visible component, nothing happens but if the now hidden component is clicked, it should become visible and the visible one goes back to being hidden.

**Content.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Panel from "../panel/Panel";
import "./content.styles.css";

const Content = ({ selected, panelA, panelB }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className={`content-wrapper ${selected ? "visible" : "hidden"}`}>
      <Panel active={active} panelText={panelA} setActive={setActive} />
      <Panel active={!active} panelText={panelB} setActive={setActive} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Content;
```

**Panel.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import "./panel.styles.css";

const Panel = ({ panelText, active, setActive }) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    if(!active){
      setActive(false);
    }
  };


  return (
    <div
      onClick={handleClick}
      className={`panel-wrapper ${
        active ? "active-component" : "hidden-component"
      }`}
    >
      {panelText}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Panel;
```

I really hope I'm just missing something or I'm not understanding how React is working under the hood. I really appreciate any help or advice you could give me to get me going down the right path.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-sound-cqzsb?file=/src/Panel.js) that I created should help.

#### Issues

You are almost there, but you have a couple of issues here:

1. Using only one state variable for both child components.

Since you are setting `active` to true and false, and passing the same state variable to both panels, panels will affect each other.

2. Setting active to false if panel isn't active

```
 const handleClick = () => {
    if(!active){
      setActive(false); // If the panel is not active, no reason to setActive(false)
    }
  };
```

#### Solution

1. You need to have separate identifiers for panels, that is why I used an array to keep track of active panels (if you have only two a string will also be fine)

```
const [activePanels, setActivePanels] = useState([/* initial active panels */])
```

2. You can add and remove to this array based on your panel's condition:

```
  const handleClick = () => {
    if (!active) setActivePanels([panelText]);
  };
```

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you very much for your help Sinan! This is exactly what I wanted to do. I understand now thanks to you.